# Too many redirects - changing naked url -> www.example.com

Tags: nginx

I've changed my conf file so that when a user types in the domain without www it redirects to the domain with www:

```
server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

I also wish for my https for anything under /user

I get the error of too may redirects, where am I going wrong?

So I have:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/example.com/site;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location /user {
            rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
```

}

For port 443:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;

    root /var/www/example.com/site;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate //path here
    ssl_certificate_key //path here

    location / {
            rewrite ^ http://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    location /user {
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

With

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

you are telling nginx that this server block is the default server for all http requests regardless of the server name.

The directive

```
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

sets nginx to redirect all incoming traffic for this server block to www.example.com. That redirected traffic hits the same server block again (default server) and the process repeats itself, hence a redirect loop.

To fix this change your config file and add a second server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name www.example.com;

    #rest of your config 
    [...]

    }

server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
   }
```

Port 80 can be left out, as it is the default, in case you are wondering.

The same principle applies to traffic for 443 (in the redirect block you however must give the port and ssl specific configuration).